# PIR Sensor mounting

Tags: lighting

[image]

A [Sensorswitch PIR sensor (right)](https://www.acuitybrands.com/products/detail/775070/sensor-switch/sbor-series/outdoor-pole-high-mount) was purchased because (hopefully) it will provide [years of service](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/201896/outdoor-motion-sensor-light-durability) in the hot Florida sun.

It would be nice if could be installed in the Defiant (Home Depot) fixture (left): I do not have confidence in the Defiant brand fixture sensors lifespan.  The problem is that the angle of the fixture is at 45 degrees and not 90.  As I see it the options are:

- find [another fixture](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Progress-Lighting-2-Light-11-3-in-Outdoor-Black-Wall-Light-P5203-31/202599675)
- find an adapter

Are there any other options that I have not considered?  The constraint is that the Acuity sensor must be used in the design.  Thanks!